# Ruby On Rails - Ошибка стилизации

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, form

Я изучаю Ruby On Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl. Делаю форму для регистрации (Глава 7).

Шаблон `new.html.erb`:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
<div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>

        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>

        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>

        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

        <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

стиль приложения (у меня в `custom.css.scss`):

```
@import "bootstrap";

/* variables */
$paddingTopBody: 60px;
$marginBottomH1: 10px;
$grayMediumLight: #eaeaea;

@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* universal */

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  padding-top: $paddingTopBody;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  h1 {
    margin-bottom: $marginBottomH1;
  }
}

/* typography */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: $grayLight;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}

/* header */

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;

  &:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

/* footer */

footer {
  margin-top: 45px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid $grayMediumLight;
  color: $grayLight;

 a {
    color: $gray;
    &:hover {
       color: $grayDarker;
    }
  }

  small {
    float: left;
  }

  ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    li {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
  }

  /* miscellaneous */

  .debug_dump {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 45px;
    @include box_sizing;
  }

  /* sidebar */

  aside {
    section.user_info {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    section {
      padding: 10px 0;
      margin-top: 20px;
      &:first-child {
        border: 0;
        padding-top: 0;
      }
      span {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
        line-height: 1;
      }
      h1 {
        font-size: 1.4em;
        text-align: left;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
        margin-top: 0px;
      }
    }
  }

  .gravatar {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }

  .gravatar_edit {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }

  /* forms */

  input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    @include box_sizing;
  }

  input {
    height: auto !important;
  }
}
```

Мой результат:[image: Результат]

Результат учебника: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наконец, нашел ошибку. Я забыл поставить `}` в конце `footer`, и все, что шло после него не работало для всей страницы